# How to add an element to array?

Tags: php, arrays

How to add element to exist array? I have array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 1 [user_login] => Saibamen [user_password] => 4028a0e356acc947fcd2bfshfh3w26gdshhbf00cef11e128d484a [user_email] => teeeest@test.pl [user_active] => 1 [user_last_login_ip] => 127.0.0.1 [user_perms] => ) )
```

I want add 'avatar' parametr to this array:

```
$avatar = md5($array_in_this_question[0]['user_email'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you'd need to assign the array to a variable for a start, so:

```
$theArray = Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 1 [user_login] => Saibamen [user_password] => 4028a0e356acc947fcd2bfshfh3w26gdshhbf00cef11e128d484a [user_email] => teeeest@test.pl [user_active] => 1 [user_last_login_ip] => 127.0.0.1 [user_perms] => ) );
$theArray[0]['avatar'] = md5($array_in_this_question[0]['user_email']);
```

is what you want I guess

Answer (score 1):

You add value the same way as when you read a value: By using its key(s)

```
$array_in_this_question[0]['avatar'] = md5($array_in_this_question[0]['user_email']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make

```
$array[0]['avatar'] = $avatar
```

Comment: This would add the value to the outer hash, not the internal one (which he probably wants).